# Wildcard SSL subdomain format

Tags: ssl

I previously used this pattern `x.example.com` to identify different servers. I had no problem with my wildcard SSL cert with this.

Recently I switched to a new scheme that contains more information, like:

```
a.b.c.example.com
```

Now the browser tells me:

```
You attempted to reach a.b.example.com, but instead you actually
reached a server identifying itself as *.example.com. This may be
caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious
```

Why is this happening?

I assumed that `a.b.example.com` would be the same as something like `a-b.example.com`.

Comment: Wildcards only apply to a single level. a.example.com is covered, but a.b.example.com is a two-level and isn't covered. You'd need `*.*.example.com` and `*.*.*.example.com` for certs as well

Comment: No -- wildcard certs only work for a single level.

Comment: @MarcB is there a thing as `*.*.example.com` or you have to buy `*.a.example.com`, `*.b.example.com`?

Comment: @MarcB If you'd have posted is as an answer, I'd have accepted it :)